# Most efficient way to swap () for {} in VsCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code and often find myself having to replace parentheses `(<code>)` with curly brackets `{<same code>}` or vice versa. So far I haven't found a way to do this other than manually backspacing and replacing each character.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Is it strictly `()` or is is `(some other stuff you're not telling us about, and varies place to place)`?

Comment: if it just () or {} you can use ctrl + h and just replace all match case

Comment: Good point, it's parentheses with contents. I've updated original question. Thanks.

Comment: Hi G - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below an answer, or edit your question to clarify what else you want to know. Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" to close out the question, and/or upvote any answers you found helpful. If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer to close out the question. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 3):

You can use the regex search and replace capability within VSCode.

Make this your search string:

```
(.*)(\()(.*)(\))
```

Replace with:

```
$1{$3}
```

Explanation:

1. We are using regex capture groups to allow us to retain some parts of the search string whilst replacing other parts.
2. The first capture group `(.*)` searches for and captures anything preceeding the first `(` character.
3. The second capture group `(\()` gets the left parenthesis - which we will replace with a `{`. Notice that the `(` is escaped, because `(` is an operator in regex
4. The third capture group `(.*)` grabs whatever is inside the parentheses - we will put that back again.
5. The final capture group `(\))` grabs the `)` char, which we swap out for a `}`
6. So, `$2` and `$4` capture groups contain the `(` and `)` characters, which we replace with literal `{` and `}` characters. *(If we wanted to put back exactly what we had found, we would put: `$1$2$3$4` as the replace text)*

#### Important:

Note (see below img) that the `[.*]` button is clicked *(to the right of the search text)*

[image: VSCode Search box showing RegEx button depressed]

That `[.*]` button makes the search a regex search. Make sure you unclick it when done.

#### More Important:

***Do not hit the `Replace All` button - do the replacements one-by-one. This particular regex will not correctly replace multi-line text inside the parens.*** But for speeding up the process, Bob's yer uncle.

<kbd>[**DEMO at RegEx101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/7Kilz6/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I have only briefly tested it but have a look at [bracketeer extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pustelto.bracketeer).

After installing it with the cursor anywhere within the brackets you want to swap, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> (or a more convenient keybinding) to cycle between `[], {}, and ()`.  It seems to work well even with nested brackets.

Test with your language - it doesn't support many but may work for you (it appears there is no html support though yet).  Obviously, this only works on a chosen instance - not file-wide - but it does work with multiple cursors.